# Executing a perl program with the perl in server

Tags: perl

I need to execute a program in my system using the perl.exe from a network path.what change should I have to change in the interpreter line to execute that..?

Comment: change the shebang (interpreter) line to the network path.

Comment: @user1937198 shebang is useless in Windows (note the .exe)

Comment: The shebang isn't used to resolve the interpreter executable on Windows systems. Windows associates the interpreter with file type associations, while Unix systems mostly use magic numbers.

Answer (score 2):

There's a fair chance (given that the question gives us no clues to help us answer it) that the perl.exe is just a wrapper for perl.dll, so if the perl.exe isn't on the path (and it won't be if its on a network share) then the exe will fail to run.

The answer is almost certainly to copy the required files locally and run them there. I recommend [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) for Windows, as its just a directory copy to get it installed.

Comment: if i execute the code using the command line (path of perl.exe) (link to my perl file), then the code works. But i cant find a way to run it automatically just by opening the perl file.

Comment: Set perl.exe as the default 'viewer' of your .pl programs - right click on your program and when Windows pops up a dialog asking which program to use to open the file, browse and select perl.exe

Comment: i cant install perl in my pc, i need to use it from my network path only.. So the perl will not be listed in the properties itself

Answer (score 0):

Invoking using a remote exe may not work due to the exe's own dependencies. Consider packaging your perl script as an exe using http://search.cpan.org/dist/PAR-Packer/